# Webpack, проблема с react-router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Всегда работал с create-react-app. Взялся за Webpack, настроил, все работало до роутинга. Вылетает ошибка при переходе на другой адрес: "Cannot get /(Введенный path)"

Webpack.config:

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public"
  },

  mode: "development",

  watch: true,

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["env", "stage-0", "react"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 40000,
            name: "[path][name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "img/"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx"]
  }
};
```

Корневой компонент с роутами:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './Home'
import NotFound from './NotFound'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>  
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Только что протестировал через Link - работает. Значит, ошибка вылетает при принудительной перезагрузке страницы, однако, через CRA такого не было. Надеюсь на ваш совет как это устранить :)

Comment: Попробуйте <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />

Comment: Дело не в этом, нужно использовать HashRouter

Comment: А зачем, чем create-react-app не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло добаление 2-х строк в webpack.config

output: {
publicPath: '/',
},

devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
}

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился. Нужно вместо BrowserRouter использовать HashRouter, и все будет работать.