# проблема с путями при ручном вводе в адресной строке

Tags: reactjs, webpack

при ручном вводе пример (http://localhost:4200/dialogs/Dialogs)

соответствующий js и css файлы ищутся в каталоге dialogs но они находятся в dist/css и dist/js
а при переходе через интерфейс(клик) все отлично работает
**собственно вопрос какая настройка в webpack за это отвечает**

результат примера

1. http://localhost:4200/dialogs/js/vendors~main.js
2. http://localhost:4200/dialogs/css/main.css

Comment: отсутствовал publickPath:'/' https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842834/webpack-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-react-router?rq=1